# .htaccess: как преобразовать ссылки?

Tags: url, .htaccess

Как сделать с помощью .htaccess так, чтобы при запросе страницы `/index?id=1234` запрашивалась `/index.php?id=1234` и, соответственно, для всех остальных страниц тоже, то есть:

```
/test?id=1234 <=> /test.php?id=1234
```

Answer (score 1):

А вот мой вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\?(.+) $1.php?$2 [L]
```

Так должно заработать. Комментатор чуть повыше не учел, что RewriteEngine нужно еще и включить. Ну как бы со всеми бывает.

Comment: Не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так делал

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\?(.+) $1.php?$2 [L]
```

**Обновление**

Добавь

```
# Log to a file:
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
```

Потом покажи, что там происходит.

Comment: Не помогло.

Comment: Что говорит? Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да ничего, так же 404.

Answer (score 0):

Должен быть включен `mod_rewrite` в файле .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1\.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error